# JupyterLab Error FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, jupyter-lab

I am using JupyterLab on a MacOS Big Sur and Chrome browser. Before today I could upload files to JupyterLab and simply "copy path" into e.g. pd.read_csv('') and it would be recognized. It will recognize the path to a file on my desktop but not a file uploaded to JupyterLab. I would appreciate any help

Comment: A useful thing for me to do is often to type `!ls` and execute a cell to see if the file is in the directory that the kernel actually sees. If not, check what is your `!cwd` and compare with the expected directory path.

Comment: Without any deep knowledge. When I was facing the problem, I just restarted the kernel and it worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I use the exact same setup. Jupyter Lab opens in Chrome, but it uses files from your local directories. Therefore files aren't uploaded. If you copy path directly from Jupyter it will give you the relative path. If you need the absolute path you have to find the file in your local directory.

Comment: What might have been new and caused the problem was that I created a folder in JL and placed my three notebooks. I got rid of the new folder and placed the notebook and csv files all in the main location and now when I "copy path" it finds the file. I don't really understand why that made a difference. Many thanks

Comment: The main location is your current working directory. In your working directory you can write a path as "filename.csv". When you create a new folder within your current working directory, that is a sub directory and you can write the path as "new_folder_name/filename.csv". That is the problem.